# How to insert audit filters into community edition?

Tags: mariadb

When it comes to auditing, majority of documentation I find pertains to enterprise edition, not community. It is a different plugin and as such not all information I read matches up.
Running MariaDB 10.3 with the server audit plugin (1.4 I believe).  Enterprise documentation says I can insert filters (in json) into the mysql.server_audit_filters table. However, I have no such table. I can't find anything about how I can implement filters into the non-enterprise edition. In fact, I can't see any tables in the mysql database that relate to the audit plugin. Can someone point me in the right direction?  Does this plugin simply have its own set of fixed filters and cannot be altered?

Comment: "Free" products need a way to make money.

Comment: Uh ok? Not sure what free has to do with my question.

Comment: "Community" is 'free'; "Enterprise" is not.  The latter has plugins that the former does not have.

Comment: no kidding. I suppose that's why I mentioned the alternative plugin and asked about it.

Comment: Right direction? [Here's some code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.2/plugin/server_audit/server_audit.c), you can write the required features yourself. Please do make it into a free available product when you're finished. I hear there's quite a demand.

Comment: A simple "no that plugin can not do that, it logs everything by default" would have sufficed instead of a bunch of smartass answers.